# How can I re-label the "Password" field on the Django 1.11 login page?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, customization

I want to customise the appearance of the "Password" field on the Django 1.11 login page. Specifically, I want to change the label from "Password" to "Passphrase" while maximising re-use of default Django code.

For other forms I have done this subclassing as follows:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from x import BaseForm

class CustomForm(BaseForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["fieldname"].label = _("Custom label")
```

...but simply subclassing [AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) has no effect, so I assume I have to hook it up somehow. And/or subclass [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)?

Comment: any luck with this? Facing the same issue with `labels = {'password1': "Choose a password (atleast 8 characters)",` when I extend `UserCreationForm`. Password's label doesnt change while other fields are ok